# Why use outer `section` element in HTML5 markup?

Tags: html

Why would a HTML5 website adopt the following structure? I am specifically interested in the use of the outer `<section>` element.

I realise that this validates as HTML5, but I do not understand why a section would contain an article. I thought that a section was to be thought of like a "chapter" of an article. Why wouldn't one just use `<div id="main"> ... </div>`? Is there a semantic advantage (perhaps for SEO) of using the outer section element?

**Note: I have simplified the source by removing various container / inner wrapper DIV elements.**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="main">
        <article id="home">
            <section class="block">
                <h1>Heading</h1>
                <p>Content...</p>
                <p>Content...</p>
            </section>
            <section class="block">
                <p>Content...</p>
                <p>Content...</p>
            </section>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
```

*I am unable to provide a link to the website in question because it contains content that some viewers may find offensive.*

Comment: Actually, a `section` can be used for many purposes, besides just a denoting sections of a single article. It's *almost* as flexible as a `div`, except more semantic.

Comment: @BoltClock - (Completely off-topic) congratulations on your promotion to moderator! I was very happy to see you win one of the open positions.

Comment: @James Allardice: Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element):

> The section element represents a generic document or application
>   section…The section element is not a generic container element. When
>   an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for
>   scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead.

And:

> Examples of sections would be chapters, the various tabbed pages in a
>   tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis. A Web site's
>   home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news
>   items, and contact information.

So in my opinion, what you have demonstrated is not really a valid semantic use for the `section` element, and `div` would be better (or nothing at all, considering there is already the wrapper `div`). However, the two child `section` elements are probably used more as the spec intended.

I don't believe any of the HTML5 elements (`article`, `section` etc.) have any real bearing on SEO at the moment, although they could in the future. And I may be wrong. I'm not an SEO expert.

Comment: Would the outer `section` be valid if there were more than one of them, each of which contained multiple articles? cheers

Comment: In my opinion that would be semantically valid (note that it definitely is syntactically valid, as is your original example), as long as the child `articles` are all related. I think `section` elements should be used to group related content.

Comment: Yes I agree that would make the most sense. So presumably the only way to group unrelated articles would be with a `div`. Cheers

Comment: Yes, the `div` is intended for grouping elements when no other semantically-relevant element exists. Just bear in mind that using any is fine from a syntax point of view. Personally, I wouldn't worry too much about the subtleties of semantics between them.

Answer (score 1):

without seeing it in action, kinda hard to say exactly but here goes: the outer section element is more than likely establishing the sites desired document outline. if that is not the desired outcome then i agree with @james allardice, a div would be better there (especially since there is no headline for the outer section). if that is the desired outcome, then using the outer section establishes a generic section in the sites document outline, with its child elements nested inside, so that it can generate the appropriate document map. user agents can then use the document map to generate a table of contents, which can then be used by at's.

you can test a documents outline here: http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/

Comment: Thanks for the link, the outline for the website in question is quite deep and seems overkill given what it actually contains. I will have a play with different sites to see what the outline tool produces.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty semantic. A Web site's home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news items, contact information.

At the moment I don't think any weight is gained for HTML5 semantics with SEO, but in the future - it will probably be key.